# fb:swf not working

Tags: flash, facebook

Trying to embed Flash into a HTML page using FBML tag fb:swf and I get this error. Tried looking around didn't work any ideas? Pretty stuck here

FBML Error (line 5): illegal tag "body" under "fb:canvas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not allowed to use **body** tag in fbml apps. If there is one, remove it.